# Jquery 3.6.0: iframe load callback not called

Tags: jquery, iframe, load

Jquery 3.6: iframe load callback not called.

```
iframeFoo.contentWindow.document.open();
iframeFoo.contentWindow.document.write("<html><body></body></html>");
iframeFoo.contentWindow.document.close();

$(iframeFoo).load(function() {
        alert("Hello");
});
```

It was working for Jquery 1.11.x.
The event was not fired for Jquery 3.6.0.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to replace your `load(function())` for:

```
$(iframeFoo).on('load', function(){
 alert("Hello");
});
```

From the jquery documentation

> Note: This API has been removed in jQuery 3.0; please use .on( "load",
> handler ) instead of .load( handler ) and .trigger( "load" ) instead
> of .load().
> new code: